# reading pixel values in 16-bit grayscale PNG in delphi

Tags: delphi-xe2

I have been trying to read pixel values from 16-bit grayscale images (.PNG), but I am unable to extract the 16-bit values. They always come out as 8-bit values.

The image loads nicely with this code:

```
PngImage := TPngImage.Create;  
PngImage.LoadFromFile(ImageFile);
```

and

```
PngImage.Header.ColorType returns: COLOR_GRAYSCALE
PngImage.Header.BitDepth returns: 16
```

I then declare the variables:

```
pngrowdata,extrapngrowdata: pWordArray;
```

and read them using:

```
PngRowData := PngImage.Scanline[y];
ExtraPngRowData := PngImage.ExtraScanline[y];
```

where `y` is a line number in the image.

The problem is that for all values of x PngRowData[x] is identical to ExtraPngRowData[x], i.e. I do not get the high and the low byte of a 16-bit value.
The documentation of Extrascanline in the Embarcadero help file is lacking, it is only stated that this function is used to read the second byte of
the 16-bit pixels and that Scanline is used to read the first byte,

Does anyone have a clue? Just to check the image used, I can load it to ImageJ and in that program the pixels are read nicely as 16-bit integers.

Claus

Comment: Could you provide a link to the image, or similarly formatted image, so we can test ourselves?

Comment: Here is a link to a small sector of my 16-bit grayscale image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v40kdpciirayyq6/16bit%20grayscale%20test%20image.png

Comment: I also tried to use pByteArray instead of pWordArray, but that does not solve the problem. Interestingly PngImage.Pixels[x,y] seems to return the correct value multiplied by 256, but this function is much too slow for scanning of the entire image.

Comment: Well, it seems that the problem may be that the 16-bit grayscale image is loaded in Delphi as a 8-bit image (using either PngImage.LoadFromFile or PngImage.LoadFromStream, where PngImage is of type TPngImage). - Could that be correct?

Comment: I reproduced your problem.  It appears to be a bug in tPngImage.  It should be reported to Embarcadero.   I used Corel Photo-Paint to confirm that the image can be opened and that the 16-bit values are present and accessible.  I wrote a Delphi XE-5 program to load the PNG and called ScanLine and ExtraScanLine.  They returned different pointers, but the values pointed to were the same.  I couldn't find any way to access the LSB.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I will report the bug to Embarcadero.